# understanding this NP-complete optimization?

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization

Has anyone seen this problem before? It's supposed to be NP-complete.

> We are given vertices V_1,...,V_n and possible parent sets for each vertex. Each parent set has an associated cost. Let O be an ordering (a permutation) of the vertices. We say that a parent set of a vertex V_i is consistent with an ordering O if all of the parents come before the vertex in the ordering. Let mcc(V_i, O) be minimum cost of the parent sets of vertex V_i that are consistent with ordering O. I need to find an ordering O that minimizes the total cost: mcc(V_1, O), ... ,mcc(V_n, O).

I don't quite understand the part "...if all of the parents come before the vertex in the ordering." What does it mean?

Comment: Maybe it means the triangle inequality?

Comment: Proofreading note: the "be the minimum cost of the parent sets of vertex $V_i$" bit is repeated twice in your text. Also, are the strings surrounded by $'s supposed to display as anything in particular? If they are, it's not working for me.

Comment: @weronika the $ symbols surround mathematical expressions in latex. It works well for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ but not in this site. We could just remove them and put italics.

Comment: This is a question coming from [University of Waterloo assignment](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs486/Assignments/a1.pdf) the linked PDF gives more detail and examples about the question.

Comment: @Vitalij - Oh, I see. I did the edit, but it's in the moderation queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I haven't seen that problem before.

As for the bit you're not sure about - an ordering is just an order of all the vertices, so I think "if all the parents come before the vertex in the ordering" just means exactly what it says. For instance, say (A, B) is one parent set of D: that parent set is consistent with the ordering [A,B,C,D], since A and B are before D, and not consistent with the ordering [A,D,B,C], since B is after D; however, say (A) is another parent set of D - that one is consistent with both those orderings.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So the problem is asking to find a topological sort of the vertices?

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij - to be honest I'm not sure whether the problem has any topological meaning - the text of the question doesn't seem to have any relation to graphs beyond calling the items vertices.  Any specific interpretation of what the desired ordering is would depend on what the parent sets and associated costs are.